# Windows 8 search keeps showing my app name in lowercase

Tags: windows-8, wix

I've created an desktop app for Windows and a corresponding WiX installer. Let's assume my app is called "Foo". The main executable and all app references are called "Foo", with caital "F".
But Windows 8 search (the one which pops up when you enter the Start screen and begin typing) only finds the reference to my app when I type it with "f" in lowercase and shows my app name with lowercase "f" in the beginning.

Here's how I register the Start screen reference in WiX:

```
<RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications" Name="Foo" Value="SOFTWARE\Foo\Capabilities" Type="string" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Foo.exe" Value="[!Foo.exe]" Type="string" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Foo.exe" Name="Path" Value="[APPLICATIONFOLDER]" Type="string" />
```

Is there a way to tell the Windows indexing service how should it index a particular executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you are asking, I would add a shortcut to the windows 8 start menu search by creating a `Shortcut` element. You would tie that in to a `Directory` element, see general example below:

```
<Feature Id="StartMenuShortcut" >
        <Component Id="StartMenuShortcut" Guid="SOME-GUID-HERE" Directory="ApplicationProgramsFolder" >
            <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut"
                      Name="Foo"
                      Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]\foo.exe"
                      WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"
                      Icon="SomeIconFileHereIfYouHaveOne.ico"/>
            <RemoveFolder Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" On="uninstall"/>
            <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="Software\Microsoft\MyApplicationName" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1"
                           KeyPath="yes"/>
        </Component>
    </Feature>
```

Not only will this give you the start menu display name you desire for Foo.exe, but if Foo is ever uninstalled, this shortcut will be removed with it.

Hope this helps.